# If I create a new index in MYSQL with all the primary key and other field will it take more space?

Tags: mysql

suppose I have created one table with fields A, B,C & D, where A & B are primary key. Now I want to create a seconday index based on fields A, B & c. Will this consume more space in MYSQL as I am creating index based on 3 fields or it will combine primary index with seconday index to minimize space required for index.

Comment: Even if it did combine them it would take more room than if you didn't perform any action. Plus btw it doesn't combine them

Comment: Yes, it will occupy more space.  It is unclear why you would need the extra index.  Off-hand, I can't think of a query where it would help, other than by including the third column in the index (which is a minor consideration given that (A,B) is a primary key.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Just want to know if there is any other effective way to to make a search optimized which will be based on A, B & C or we just have to create a secondary index on A, B &C.

Comment: I got little messed up in asking this question. Sorry for that. Consider this scenario. I have a table with fields A, B, C & D with A & B as key fields. We generally have large number of records with same value of A. Now I want to search the table with A & C then I have to create an index on A &C. No other option right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Creating unnecessary indexes take more space but you only need to worry about that if it not performance-efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Creating another index will consume more space. MySQL can optimize indexes (it's called Index Merge Optimization) while searching for columns in different indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If `A, B` is the *primary key*, then (in MySQL) you have the following considerations:

- Each combination of A/B is unique.
- The values are not `NULL`.
- The table is "clustered" (that is ordered) by the pair of values.

It is hard to imagine a situation where an index on `A, B, C` would be a *good* idea.  After all, a query such as:

```
select c
from table t
where a = 'a' and b = 'b'
```

would make pretty optimal use of the primary key index.  There are some outlier cases where such an index might have a marginal improvement.  But, in all likelihood, you don't need an index on `(A, B, C)`.